# A sci-fi prison where you don't age

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

- A sci-fi prison where you don't age
- The main character is male, he gets sent to prison (unsure if he committed the crime)
- He keeps trying to escape, earning the nickname slider
- The walls are like liquid air so running through them can kill you
- He ends up escaping to find his daughter is an old woman
- "Skip to my lou" is sung at odd intervals throughout the film

Comment: Sounds interesting

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess you're talking about [*Spoiler* (1998)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120187/)

"Roger Mason is a prisoner locked away in a futuristic fortress of a jail. Desperate to escape and see his daughter, he keeps making attempt after attempt to break free, but each one is foiled just as he's about to gain his freedom. As his punishments include being frozen in suspended animation for years at a time, he stays the same age while his daughter grows older. As more time keeps being added to his sentence, he despairs of ever getting out..."

Comment: Nice answer. +1 and welcome to MTVSE.